# Is it possible to auto-magically bind to path without explicitly specifying it?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm not sure if it's possible at all, although (being lazy... hrmp... **efficient**) I still want to ask. *DataGrid* has the functionality to automatically create columns based on the fields of the elements sent into it.

However, in my application, we have disabled data editing in-line and instead when when the user clicks on a row, a dialog pops up and it's used to edit the values for each of the fields of the object corresponding to the row clicked.

I'm sending in the object corresponding to the row clicked into the dialog and use it as it's data context. It means, at the moment, that I need to specify each field's binding explicitly, as follows.

```
<TextBox x:Name="SomeName"
         Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxStyle}"
         Text="{Binding Path=SomeProperty,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

I'm curious if it's possible somehow to make the fields "kind-of-realize" that they need to pick their bound values from the data context's fields (based on their names or such). Something like this.

```
<TextBox x:Name="CertainString"
         Style="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxStyle}"
         Text="{Binding CertainStringOrSomething}" />
```

Comment: What you're looking for is a PropertyGrid.  It's an editor that automatically creates editors for all (saving those marked with special attributes) public properties on an instance of a type.  I don't think WPF has a native impl, but you can find implementations on your own using a search engine.  Ask for one and I'll punch a baby, so please don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way to achieve this (if I got your question right), is to do this with a `MultiValueConverter`. You pass the whole ViewModel and the name of your current Xaml-element to the converter.

```
<TextBlock Name="FirstName">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource propertyResolver}">
            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" Path="Name"/>
            <Binding Path="Person"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

In the converter, you access the property with relfection and return it:

```
public class PropertyResolver : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, 
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(values[1] is Person)) throw new ArgumentException("please pass a person");

        var person = (Person)values[1];
        var property = values[0].ToString();

        return person.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(person, null);
    }
}
```

(ExampleData: the ViewModel contains the propery `public Person Person { get; set; }` and the class Person has the property `FirstName` in this example.)